# React Native inputs on iOS and Android

Tags: react-native

I've been evaluating React Native as a replacement for Cordova, and was wondering if there is a widely accepted solution for styled text inputs. I'd like to see text inputs rendered in Material Design on Android, and Apple style on iOS.

Do you have recommendations for a specific library, or will I have to write my own/combine multiple libraries? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out https://nativebase.io/ it supports platform specific default styling there are others as well like https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/ and http://www.xinthink.com/react-native-material-kit/ which has consistent styling regardless of platform.

Coming from a Cordova/Sencha Touch background I suggest you try to create your own style using only the default react native components, the reason is that before I was having the same question regarding component library that I could use so that I could target all platform at once, but react native isn't 100% cross platform and learning to style on different platform might give you an idea and feedback with your evaluation, unless your aiming to have a project as soon as possible and that is a different story.